# Finding functions for the squeeze theorem for $\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac {x}{\sin x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I was solving a problem today and at one point I had to evaluate the $\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac {x}{\sin x}}$. I know I could easily do this with L'hôspital's but I haven't learned that yet.

So what I did was try to use the squeeze theorem with the two bounding functions of $ f (x)=x^2 + 1 $ and $ h (x)=-x^2 +1 $, and it worked (I think?) giving me the answer of 1. However, I was only able to choose those two functions after googling the graph of $\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac {x}{\sin x}}$, so that kind of ruins the purpose. Is there a way I could have visualized this or chosen other, more fitting functions?

Or maybe there is another way to solve this limit?

Comment: The same limit is discussed in this question: [How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1). It is one of limits which appear on this site [quite often](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits?sort=frequent&pageSize=50).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint given by OC-Sansoo is not enough, which only shows that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin x}{x}=0$.

What  you should do is to prove that $\cos x < \dfrac{\sin x}{x} < 1$ for $x \in (-\pi/2,0)$.

Since $x \in (-\pi/2,0)$, $-x \in (0, \pi/2)$, hence, $\cos (-x) < \dfrac{\sin (-x)}{-x} < 1$, and hence  $\cos x < \dfrac{\sin x}{x} < 1$.

---

Another way:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x-\sin 0}{x-0}=\sin'(x)\big|_{x=0}=\cos x|_{x=0}=\cos 0=1$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Prove that: $\cos x < \dfrac{\sin x}{x} < 1$ for $x \in (0,\pi/2)$

Comment: What made you choose $cosx $ and 1? Edit: Nevermind, I see it makes sense. Thank you!